# Navigation Bar Jumps to the Top Immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Edit: I apologize, it seems it was an issue with offline hosting the website. After transferring everything over to the domain the problem I had is no longer an issue. Though it does bring up the question as to why it would load incorrectly via the same browser by keeping all the files in a folder on the desktop vs having it run through a host.

I have a rather strange issue with a website I'm trying to develop. Anytime I make a single change to the page, and about 75% of the time when trying to load it normally the navigation bar bugs out. Unless you hit the "maximize window" button twice on the browser, the nav-bar no longer retains it's intended positioning and jumps to top immediately on scroll. Anytime you attempt it after the maximize window button has been pressed twice, it works without a hitch. Here is my current HTML, CSS, and JS. Feel free to ignore the sarcasm in my note tags, and the fact that the page is mostly incomplete. I'm just trying to fix some issues before pressing on.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>The Den</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="style.css">
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- It would be nice to know if tables are what's throwing off my entire website or not... but whatever. -->
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="container"><!--I'll change the word "container" to Logo perhaps in the future here if I can get this example to work for once. Also let it be noted that I am in fact not using the "header" tag at any portion during this... which is bothersome. -->         
        <center><a href="http://www.wolvesofthedust.com/"><img src="http://i1288.photobucket.com/albums/b494/ShadowfangInnovia/WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader_zpsdddba823.png" height="auto" width="940" border="0" alt=" photo WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader_zpsdddba823.png"/></a></center>

        <!-- The navigation portion... dear God... here is where it all usually goes wrong. -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="clearfix"> <!-- Clearfix?! Really?! I'm ASSUREDLY changing that one. -->
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- End the hiddeously named section... and hopefully begin progress towards a complete page... -->

        <br/><br/>
        <h2>TEXT TEST FOR TESTING TEXT</h2> <!-- This is where I will likely have the table located with nicely written dialogue... but if the table isn't needed above then I may as well continue this practice elsewhere. Did I learn all about tables and arranging code properly for nothing? -->

        <p><!-- Interestingly enough it took me a while to realize that P stood for paragraph... considering people normally only wrote a single sentance per line with a "p" tag. Stupid examples and my insinuations based on them -->The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 93%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
    color: blue;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {margin-top: 0;}

p {margin: 0 0 1em 0;}

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    background-color: #305782;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 60px 25px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #e7ecf2;
}

.nav-placeholder {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.fixed .nav-inner {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.fixed .nav-inner-most {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #e7ecf2;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

nav ul li a:link,
nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #7d0000;
    color: #7d0000;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #28bfa1;
    color: #FFF
}

/* This seems to have an undesired effect, but may be necessary for later.
   The border-right: none; attribute is especially annoying...

nav ul li:last-child a:link,
nav ul li:last-child a:visited {
    border-right: none;
}

*/

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // define variables
    var navOffset, scrollPos = 0;

    // add utility wrapper elements for positioning
    jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery("nav").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"></div>');
    jQuery(".nav-inner").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner-most"></div>');

    // function to run on page load and window resize
    function stickyUtility() {

        // only update navOffset if it is not currently using fixed position
        if (!jQuery("nav").hasClass("fixed")) {
            navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
        }

        // apply matching height to nav wrapper div to avoid awkward content jumps
        jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

    } // end stickyUtility function

    // run on page load
    stickyUtility();

    // run on window resize
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        stickyUtility();
    });

    // run on scroll event
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
        }

    });

});
```

Thank you in advance,

Shadowfang

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Shadowfang/Lgr24gm3/2/ 

I will warn you though, it doesn't seem to work at all in the playground. But when loading the code up in the browser it works fine, aside of the hiccup with the maximizing.

Comment: Added jQuery as an external library to the jsfiddle and it seems to work pretty good - https://jsfiddle.net/Lgr24gm3/5/ Am i missing anything?

Comment: No, you have everything. Perhaps it's an issue with Chrome? Each of those files is being saved to a notepad++ document and opened through the browser that way.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't yet specified your target link, inside the href.

```
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
```

The '#' symbol in href="#" doesn't specify an id name, but does have a corresponding location - the top of the page. Clicking an anchor with href="#" will move the scroll position to the top.

This is why it jumps to top immediately. You will have to specify where you want the links to lead the user.

Comment: I just removed the anchor tags entirely from the list, and it is still doing it. I'm not clicking on the navigation bar if that's what you thought. The problem is on page load it has about a 75% chance of forcing the navigation bar to the top of the page after scrolling down "one click." But after hitting the maximize button twice on the browser it fixes itself and becomes a sticky navigation bar as intended.